# Why is #foo in the URL replaced with #/foo

Tags: angularjs, hashtag

When I use `#` in the url, it is turned into `#/` and I loose the hashtag location.
I don't use any routing settings, and for some reason this is what happens, any ideas why?

Comment: That's the way angular works, and it's probably done to prevent that exact thing from happening

Answer (score 0):

Indeed this is the way it is specified see the [specs](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.%24location), under the documentation of method `path(path`.